# Could an international tribunal or the United Nations suphoena members of the former USA goverment because of 9/11?

Tags: international, united-nations-charter

In 2010  the sixth President of Iran [Mahmoud Ahmadinejad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmoud_Ahmadinejad) offered 3 points explaining who was responsible for the 9/11 attacks at the United Nations.

[Video Here](https://youtu.be/k4phNuwx8Hs?t=10m05s)

In point number 2 he suggests that some corrupt element withing the USA government was responsible.

According to some Western media, weeks later he stated that **the 9/11 attacks were a big lie**.

References here:

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1256161/9-11-Its-big-lie-Irans-president-declares.html

http://edition.cnn.com/2010/WORLD/meast/03/07/ahmadinejad.afghanistan/index.html

Also [Lawyers Committee for 9/11 Inquiry](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and [AE911Truth](https://www.ae911truth.org/) which is an organization endorsed by 3000 architects a engineers who demand a new investigation. Also this view is endorsed by Iranian media such us [Manoto TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manoto) and Russian media such us Russia Today.

**Could an international tribunal or the United Nations suphoena members of the former USA goverment because of  9/11?** For example people like [Dick Cheney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Cheney), [Donald Rumsfeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Rumsfeld) or even former President [George W. Bush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

Even if there were any evidence that any member of the US government were involved (there isn’t), that is a matter for the US justice system. The US is not a member of the International Criminal Court so no Supra-National body has jurisdiction.